# Aligning chemical elements in a reaction equation

Tags: align, amsmath, cases, mhchem, chemistry

As pictures tell the issue better than I could I'm just gonna insert a screenshot of the problem right off the bat.
[image: Image of the Problem]

My problem is concerning the undesired whitespace between the second column of five elements and the five pluses before the five n's. LaTeX code of same looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Maths & Chemistry Preamble %
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ce{^{235}_{92}U + ^{1}_{0}n -> ^{236}_{92}U^{*} ->[\text{85\% nuclear fission}]} 
    \begin{cases}
        \begin{align*}
            \ce{^{144}_{56}Ba &+ ^{89}_{36}Kr &+ 3^{1}_{0}n} \\
            \ce{^{144}_{55}Cs &+ ^{90}_{37}Rb &+ 2^{1}_{0}n} \\
            \ce{^{140}_{54}Xe &+ ^{94}_{38}Sr &+ 2^{1}_{0}n} \\
            \ce{^{146}_{57}La &+ ^{87}_{35}Br &+ 3^{1}_{0}n} \\
            \ce{^{160}_{62}Sm &+ ^{72}_{30}Zn &+ 4^{1}_{0}n}
        \end{align*}
    \end{cases}
\label{eq:u_1}
\end{equation}
```

Packages used are amsmath, amssymb and mhchem. All I want to achieve is to have the pluses in line while minimizing the space to the left of them.

Thank you in advance, whiterock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an array here. You may want to add one more `@{}` or some other spacer onto the left of the first column.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{4}    
\begin{equation}
    \ce{^235_92U + ^1_0n -> ^236_92U^* ->[{\SI{85}{\percent} nuclear fission}]} 
    \left\{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}\begin{array}{l@{} l@{} l@{}}
        \ce{^144_56Ba &+ ^89_36Kr &+ 3^1_0n} \\
        \ce{^144_55Cs &+ ^90_37Rb &+ 2^1_0n} \\
        \ce{^140_54Xe &+ ^94_38Sr &+ 2^1_0n} \\
        \ce{^146_57La &+ ^87_35Br &+ 3^1_0n} \\
        \ce{^160_62Sm &+ ^72_30Zn &+ 4^1_0n}
    \end{array}\right.
    \label{eq:u_1}
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, brilliant answer and kind of an instant one too. I just wish these simple alignment jobs I am always struggling to pull of wouldn't require so much effort to complete.

Comment: By the way, you could save some typing with `^235_92U`instead of `^{235}_{92}U`and `->[{...}]`instead of `->[\text{...}]`, but that's down to personal preference.

Comment: @whiterock you're welcome. Yes, sometimes this is a bit of work, but actually, I was surprised how simple it was regarding the alignment operator inside the `\ce`-command. @mhchem, to be honest, I did not take a look on the chem part, I introduced your short style to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mhchem Thank you, did not know that - fantastic to get a response directly from the creators.

Comment: @whiterock - The U 235 fission product isotopes presented in the answer to the OP differ from the product isotopes presented at another (presumably reputable UC Davis) website: ***21.6: Nuclear Fission*** at https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map:_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/21:_Nuclear_Chemistry/21.06:_Nuclear_Fission. Are the differing isotopic values, eg **Ba 144** (in the OP) vs **Ba 141** (from the website), significant, or do the differences merely represent the plethora of **Ba** isotopes that can result from the fission of U 235? Thank you!